# Purpose of maximal vs non-maximal implicit arguments

Tags: coq

I have just discovered the existence of maximal and non-maximal arguments (see [documentation](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/extensions/implicit-arguments.html#maximal-and-non-maximal-insertion-of-implicit-arguments)).

But is there some motivation to use one over the other? Is one more recent than the other? Maximal implicit arguments simply need `{}` to be created, whereas one has to use `Arguments` or `Implicit Arguments` to specify non-maximal ones. Does it mean that maximal implicit arguments should be preferred?

Answer (score 14):

> ... is there some motivation to use one over the other ?

Yes there is, but (as usual) "it depends". Let's first discuss a little bit the difference between them.

Maximally-inserted implicit (MII) arguments add the next level of "implicitness" to the language.
Ordinary (non-MII) arguments get inserted only when a function is applied to at least one argument. Furthermore, Coq inserts those arguments only **before** some provided *explicit* argument.

MII arguments are more "eager": Coq considers them inserted **after** some supplied *explicit* argument. A corner case: if a function's signature starts with an MII argument, it suffices to mention the function name (even without application) for Coq to turn it into a partially applied function (it doesn't happen with non-MII arguments). Sometimes this eager behavior helps to write succinct code and sometimes its a bit of a nuisance, because it forces us to insert otherwise redundant `@` symbols to suppress insertion of implicit arguments.

Let me show some simple examples, drawn mostly from the reference manual or the standard library.

Preamble:

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List. Import ListNotations.

Section Length.
  Variable A:Type.
```

The `length` function has non-MII first argument:

```
  Print Implicit length.
  (*
  Output:
  length : forall A : Type, list A -> nat
  Argument A is implicit
  *)
```

That's why the following simple code fails (it fails because `length` is not partially applied, so `A` is not inserted):

```
  Fail Check (fun l:list (list A) => map length l).
```

One have to write something like this to make it work:

```
  Check (fun l:list (list A) => map (@length _) l).
  (* or *)
  Check (fun l:list (list A) => map (length (A := _)) l).
  (* or *)
  Check (fun l:list (list A) => map (fun xs => length xs) l).
```

Another way would be to use MII arguments. Intuitively, in this case Coq  replaces `length` with `(@length _)`:

```
  Arguments length {A} _.
  Check (fun l:list (list A) => map length l).
End Length.
```

---

But sometimes maximally inserted arguments are getting into the way, when one wants to use some function or a constructor in its most general form (not partially applied). A working example with non-MII arguments from the `Coq.Lists.List` module:

```
Set Implicit Arguments.  (* non-MII arguments is the default behavior *)
Inductive Forall2 A B (R:A->B->Prop) : list A -> list B -> Prop :=
 | Forall2_nil : Forall2 R [] []
 | Forall2_cons : forall x y l l',
    R x y -> Forall2 R l l' -> Forall2 R (x::l) (y::l').

Theorem Forall2_refl : forall A B (R:A->B->Prop), Forall2 R [] [].
Proof. exact Forall2_nil. Qed.
```

But `exact Forall2_nil` won't work in the case of MII arguments. The `constructor` will help us, though:

```
Arguments Forall2_nil {A B} _.
Theorem Forall2_refl' : forall A B (R:A->B->Prop), Forall2 R [] [].
Proof. Fail (exact Forall2_nil). constructor. Qed.
```

---

One more instance of premature implicit argument insertion (from `Coq.Init.Logic`). This works with non-MII arguments:

```
Declare Left Step eq_stepl.
```

But, here we have to add '@':

```
Arguments eq_stepl {A} _ _ _ _ _.
Fail Declare Left Step eq_stepl.
Declare Left Step @eq_stepl.
```

---

Sometimes tactics of the form `<tactic-name> ... with (_ := _).` will fail in the presence of MII arguments. Here is another (working) example from `Coq.Init.Logic`:

```
Definition eq_ind_r :
  forall (A:Type) (x:A) (P:A -> Prop), P x -> forall y:A, y = x -> P y.
  intros A x P H y H0; elim eq_sym with (1 := H0); assumption.
Defined.
```

But MII arguments impede our progress:

```
Arguments eq_sym {A x y} _.
Definition eq_ind_r' :
  forall (A:Type) (x:A) (P:A -> Prop), P x -> forall y:A, y = x -> P y.
  intros A x P H y H0.
  Fail elim eq_sym with (1 := H0); assumption.
  (* this works *)
  elim @eq_sym with (1 := H0); assumption.
  (* or this: *)
  elim (eq_sym H0); assumption.
Defined.
```

---

> Is one more recent than the other ?

I don't know I hope someone could shed some light on it.

> Maximal implicit arguments simply need `{}` to be created, whereas one has to use `Arguments` or `Implicit Arguments` to specify non-maximal ones. Does it mean that maximal implicit arguments should be preferred ?

By default, the directive `Set Implicit Arguments.` declares non-maximally inserted implicit arguments. So Coq is conservative (but not too much) about the level of implicitness. I'd stick to non-MII arguments by default, inserting `{}` where appropriate.