# Why can't I use `app` together with `fold_right` in Coq?

Tags: coq

I'm getting a type error in the last line of the following program:

```
Require Import List.
Import ListNotations.

(* This computes to 10 *)
Compute (fold_right plus 0 [1;2;3;4]).

(* I want this to compute to [5;6;7;8] but it gives a type error instead *)
Compute (fold_right app [] [[5;6]; [7;8]]).
```

This is the error I get:

```
Error:
The term "app" has type "forall A : Type, list A -> list A -> list A" while it is expected to have type
 "Type -> ?A -> ?A" (cannot instantiate "?A" because "A" is not in its scope).
```

I don't really understand why I am getting this error. What is different between `app` and `plus` here?. Does it have to do with `app` being polymorphic while `plus` is a monomorphic `nat -> nat -> nat` function?

In case that matters, my version of Coq is 8.5.

Comment: I've tried to provide several examples of this kind of behavior in my answer  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37211899/purpose-of-maximal-vs-non-maximal-implicit-arguments). HTH.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You guessed it right: it does have something to do with `app` being polymorphic. The problem is that Coq allows implicit arguments to be inferred differently depending on whether the corresponding term is applied to arguments or not. More precisely, *non-maximal implicits* are only inserted when the term is applied to something, but not inserted if the term is used on its own, like your `app`. There are two ways to remedy the situation:

1- Force Coq to infer something for that instance, as in `fold_right (@app _) [] [[5; 6]; [7; 8]]`.

2- Use a global declaration that will make the type argument maximally inserted: `Arguments app {_} _ _.`. For more details on what this is doing, check the [reference manual](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/Reference-Manual004.html#hevea_command59)

Comment: Thanks. This perfectly answers my question.